# Error: "Variable Referenced Before Assignment" Numpy Backprop Method

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning

I'm trying to complete a HW assignment that consists of filling in a Numpy NeuralNetwork class and implementing backprop.

Currently, my training_error is not changing between epochs,

```
Epoch: 0, Train Accuracy: 10.22%, Train Cost: 3.86, Test Accuracy: 10.1%
Epoch: 1, Train Accuracy: 10.22%, Train Cost: 3.86, Test Accuracy: 10.1%
Epoch: 2, Train Accuracy: 10.22%, Train Cost: 3.86, Test Accuracy: 10.1%
Epoch: 3, Train Accuracy: 10.22%, Train Cost: 3.86, Test Accuracy: 10.1%
.
.
.
```

I feel like it's down to the way I'm trying to update the weights in the backprop method.

This is the most logical way that I've thought to implement it...

```
    def backward(self, Y_hat, Y):
        '''
        Backward pass through network. Update parameters 

        INPUT
            Y_hat: Network predicted 
                shape: (?, 10)

            Y: Correct target
                shape: (?, 10)

        RETURN 
            cost: calculate J for errors 
                type: (float)

        '''
        # calculate the cost
        cost = Y_hat-Y

        # calc gradients
        dJ_dZ2 = Y_hat - Y
        dJ_dW2 = np.matmul(np.transpose(X2), dJ_dZ2)
        dJ_db2 = Y_hat - Y
        dJ_dX2 =  np.matmul(dJ_db2, np.transpose(self.W2))
        dJ_dZ1 = dJ_dX2 * d_sigmoid(Z1)
        inner_mat = np.matmul(Y-Y_hat,np.transpose(self.W2))
        dJ_dW1 = np.matmul(np.transpose(X),inner_mat) * d_sigmoid(Z1)
        dJ_db1 = np.matmul(Y - Y_hat, np.transpose(self.W2)) * d_sigmoid(Z1)


        # weight updates
        W2 = W2 - lr * dJ_dW2
        b2 = b2 - lr * dJ_db2
        W1 = W1 - lr * dJ_dW1
        b1 = b1 - lr * dJ_db1

        return cost
```

The above code returns this error...

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-229643aebabc> in <module>()
     25 
     26         # compute gradients and update weights
---> 27         train_cost += nn.backward(Y_hat, Y)
     28 
     29     test_correct = 0

<ipython-input-20-5990c00f4f20> in backward(self, Y_hat, Y)
     68 
     69         # weight updates
---> 70         W2 = W2 - lr * dJ_dW2
     71         b2 = b2 - lr * dJ_db2
     72         W1 = W1 - lr * dJ_dW1

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'W2' referenced before assignment
```

However, I haven't been able to get it to run when it's structured like the snippet above. I've only been able to get it to run when I structure it like this...

```
        #Naked Backprop
        dJ_dZ2 = Y_hat - Y
        dJ_dW2 = np.matmul(np.transpose(X2), dJ_dZ2)
        dJ_db2 = Y_hat - Y
        dJ_dX2 =  np.matmul(dJ_db2, np.transpose(NeuralNetwork.W2))
        dJ_dZ1 = dJ_dX2 * d_sigmoid(Z1)
        inner_mat = np.matmul(Y-Y_hat,np.transpose(NeuralNetwork.W2))
        dJ_dW1 = np.matmul(np.transpose(X),inner_mat) * d_sigmoid(Z1)
        dJ_db1 = np.matmul(Y - Y_hat, np.transpose(NeuralNetwork.W2)) * d_sigmoid(Z1)

        lr = 0.1

        # weight updates here
        #just line 'em up and do lr * the dJ_.. vars you found above
        NeuralNetwork.W2 = NeuralNetwork.W2 - lr * dJ_dW2
        NeuralNetwork.b2 = NeuralNetwork.b2 - lr * dJ_db2
        NeuralNetwork.W1 = NeuralNetwork.W2 - lr * dJ_dW1
        NeuralNetwork.b1 = NeuralNetwork.b1 - lr * dJ_db1
```

I feel like this might be what's keeping my network from actually learning, not sure though.
Any advice would be amazing!

Also, here is the full script

```
import keras
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.datasets import mnist

np.random.seed(0)

"""### Load MNIST Dataset"""

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

X = x_train[0].reshape(1,-1)/255.; Y = y_train[0]
zeros = np.zeros(10); zeros[Y] = 1
Y = zeros

#Here we implement the forward pass for the network using the single example, $X$, from above

### Initialize weights and Biases

num_hidden_nodes = 200 
num_classes = 10

# init weights
#first set of weights (these are what the input matrix is multiplied by)
W1 = np.random.uniform(-1e-3,1e-3,size=(784,num_hidden_nodes))
#this is the first bias layer and i think it's a 200 dimensional vector of the biases that go into each neuron before the sigmoid function.
b1 = np.zeros((1,num_hidden_nodes))

#again this are the weights for the 2nd layer that are multiplied by the activation output of the 1st layer
W2 = np.random.uniform(-1e-3,1e-3,size=(num_hidden_nodes,num_classes))
#these are the biases that are added to each neuron before the final softmax activation.
b2 = np.zeros((1,num_classes))


# multiply input with weights
Z1 = np.add(np.matmul(X,W1), b1)

def sigmoid(z):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(- z))

def d_sigmoid(g):
    return sigmoid(g) * (1. - sigmoid(g))

# activation function of Z1
X2 = sigmoid(Z1)


Z2 = np.add(np.matmul(X2,W2), b2)

# softmax
def softmax(z):
    # subracting the max adds numerical stability
    shiftx = z - np.max(z)
    exps = np.exp(shiftx)
    return exps / np.sum(exps)

def d_softmax(Y_hat, Y):
    return Y_hat - Y

# the hypothesis, 
Y_hat = softmax(Z2)

"""Initially the network guesses all categories equally. As we perform backprop the network will get better at discerning images and their categories."""


"""### Calculate Cost"""

cost = -1 * np.sum(Y * np.log(Y_hat))


#so i think the main thing here is like a nested chain rule thing, where we find the change in the cost with respec to each 
# set of matrix weights and biases?

#here is probably the order of how we do things based on whats in math below...
'''
1. find the partial deriv of the cost function with respect to the output of the second layer, without the softmax it looks like for some reason?
2. find the partial deriv of the cost function with respect to the weights of the second layer, which is dope cause we can re-use the partial deriv from step 1
3. this one I know intuitively we're looking for the parial deriv of cost with respect to the bias term of the second layer, but how TF does that math translate into 
numpy? is that the same y_hat - Y from the first step? where is there anyother Y_hat - y?
4. This is also confusing cause I know where to get the weights for layer 2 from and how to transpose them, but again, where is the Y_hat - Y?
5. Here we take the missing partial deriv from step 4 and multiply it by the d_sigmoid function of the first layer outputs before activations.
6. In this step we multiply the first layer weights (transposed) by the var from 5
7. And this is weird too, this just seems like the same step as number 5 repeated for some reason but with y-y_hat instead of y_hat-y
'''
#look at tutorials like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7qYtIveJ6hU
#I think the most backprop layer steps are fine without biases but how do we find the bias derivatives

#maybe just the hypothesis matrix minus the actual y matrix?
dJ_dZ2 = Y_hat - Y


#find partial deriv of cost w respect to 2nd layer weights
dJ_dW2 = np.matmul(np.transpose(X2), dJ_dZ2)


#finding the partial deriv of cost with respect to the 2nd layer biases
#I'm still not 100% sure why this is here and why it works out to Y_hat - Y
dJ_db2 = Y_hat - Y


#finding the partial deriv of cost with respect to 2nd layer inputs
dJ_dX2 =  np.matmul(dJ_db2, np.transpose(W2))



#finding the partial deriv of cost with respect to Activation of layer 1
dJ_dZ1 = dJ_dX2 * d_sigmoid(Z1)



#y-yhat matmul 2nd layer weights
#I added the transpose to the W2 var because the matrices were not compaible sizes without it
inner_mat = np.matmul(Y-Y_hat,np.transpose(W2))
dJ_dW1 = np.matmul(np.transpose(X),inner_mat) * d_sigmoid(Z1)


class NeuralNetwork:
    # set learning rate
    lr = 0.01

    # init weights
    W1 = np.random.uniform(-1e-3,1e-3,size=(784,num_hidden_nodes))
    b1 = np.zeros((1,num_hidden_nodes))

    W2 = np.random.uniform(-1e-3,1e-3,size=(num_hidden_nodes,num_classes))
    b2 = np.zeros((1,num_classes))


    def __init__(self, num_hidden_nodes, num_classes, lr=0.01):
        '''
        # set learning rate
        lr = lr

        # init weights
        W1 = np.random.uniform(-1e-3,1e-3,size=(784,num_hidden_nodes))
        b1 = np.zeros((1,num_hidden_nodes))

        W2 = np.random.uniform(-1e-3,1e-3,size=(num_hidden_nodes,num_classes))
        b2 = np.zeros((1,num_classes))
    '''
    def forward(self, X1):
        '''
        Forward pass through the network

        INPUT
            X: input to network
                shape: (?, 784)

        RETURN
            Y_hat: prediction from output of network 
                shape: (?, 10)
        '''
        Z1 = np.add(np.matmul(X,W1), b1)
        X2 =  sigmoid(Z1)# activation function of Z1
        Z2 = np.add(np.matmul(X2,W2), b2)
        Y_hat =  softmax(Z2)

        #return the hypothesis
        return Y_hat

        # store input for backward pass

        # you can basically copy and past what you did in the forward pass above here

        # think about what you need to store for the backward pass

        return 

    def backward(self, Y_hat, Y):
        '''
        Backward pass through network. Update parameters 

        INPUT
            Y_hat: Network predicted 
                shape: (?, 10)

            Y: Correct target
                shape: (?, 10)

        RETURN 
            cost: calculate J for errors 
                type: (float)

        '''

        #Naked Backprop
        dJ_dZ2 = Y_hat - Y
        dJ_dW2 = np.matmul(np.transpose(X2), dJ_dZ2)
        dJ_db2 = Y_hat - Y
        dJ_dX2 =  np.matmul(dJ_db2, np.transpose(NeuralNetwork.W2))
        dJ_dZ1 = dJ_dX2 * d_sigmoid(Z1)
        inner_mat = np.matmul(Y-Y_hat,np.transpose(NeuralNetwork.W2))
        dJ_dW1 = np.matmul(np.transpose(X),inner_mat) * d_sigmoid(Z1)
        dJ_db1 = np.matmul(Y - Y_hat, np.transpose(NeuralNetwork.W2)) * d_sigmoid(Z1)

        lr = 0.1

        # weight updates here
        #just line 'em up and do lr * the dJ_.. vars you found above
        NeuralNetwork.W2 = NeuralNetwork.W2 - lr * dJ_dW2
        NeuralNetwork.b2 = NeuralNetwork.b2 - lr * dJ_db2
        NeuralNetwork.W1 = NeuralNetwork.W1 - lr * dJ_dW1
        NeuralNetwork.b1 = NeuralNetwork.b1 - lr * dJ_db1

        # calculate the cost
        cost = -1 * np.sum(Y * np.log(Y_hat))

        # calc gradients

        # weight updates

        return cost#, W1, W2, b1, b2

nn = NeuralNetwork(200,10,lr=.01)
num_train = float(len(x_train)) 
num_test = float(len(x_test))

train_correct = 0; train_cost = 0

for epoch in range(10):

    # training loop
    for i in range(len(x_train)):
        x = x_train[i]; y = y_train[i]
        # standardizing input to range 0 to 1
        X = x.reshape(1,784) /255.

        # forward pass through network
        Y_hat = nn.forward(X)

        # get pred number
        pred_num = np.argmax(Y_hat)

        # check if prediction was accurate
        if pred_num == y:
            train_correct += 1

        # make a one hot categorical vector; same as keras.utils.to_categorical()
        zeros = np.zeros(10); zeros[y] = 1
        Y = zeros

        # compute gradients and update weights
        train_cost += nn.backward(Y_hat, Y)

    test_correct = 0
    # validation loop
    for i in range(len(x_test)):
        x = x_test[i]; y = y_test[i]
        # standardizing input to range 0 to 1
        X = x.reshape(1,784) /255.

        # forward pass
        Y_hat = nn.forward(X)

        # get pred number
        pred_num = np.argmax(Y_hat)

        # check if prediction was correct
        if pred_num == y:
            test_correct += 1

        # no backward pass here!

    # compute average metrics for train and test
    train_correct = round(100*(train_correct/num_train), 2)
    test_correct = round(100*(test_correct/num_test ), 2)
    train_cost = round( train_cost/num_train, 2)

    # print status message every epoch
    log_message = 'Epoch: {epoch}, Train Accuracy: {train_acc}%, Train Cost: {train_cost}, Test Accuracy: {test_acc}%'.format(
        epoch=epoch, 
        train_acc=train_correct, 
        train_cost=train_cost, 
        test_acc=test_correct
    )
    print (log_message)
```

Comment: Can you include the Traceback? Copy the Traceback and paste it in the question, then format it as code (select it and type ctrl-k)

Comment: Good idea, I've added the traceback

Comment: Have you tried using `self.W2` instead of `NeuralNetwork.W2` everywhere in that method? Are `W2`,`b2`,`b1` all instance attributes?

Comment: Hey wwii, So I tried using self.VAR_NAME for all the variables and now it runs but it still has a static accuracy. Yes, W1, W2, b1, and b2 are all instance attributes.

Comment: `but it still has a static accuracy.` sounds like a different question than `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'W2' referenced before assignment`. you could [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) or delete it.  If you decide to ask about the other issue it will be important to include a [mcve]..